# Creating a simulated dataset which keeps the original shape of the data in R

Tags: r, simulation

I have a data set that consists of 11 variables. Of these, six of them are numeric and the other five are ordered factors based on the values of the numeric variables (i.e., is someone got a 62, then they got a D, 75 equals, C, etc).

Now I know I can create a dataset using `rnorm` and provide it with the mean and sd for each of my variables; however, my issue is that `rnorm` is normally distributed (hence the name) whereas my data is negatively skewed.

Therefore, can someone tell me how to create a simulated dataset that maintains the distribution of the original? In other words, how can you create a skewed normal distribution with a predefined mean, max, min and standard deviation?

Comment: R has functions like `rnorm()` and `runif()` that will generate random numbers on a normal or uniform distribution. Is that helpful?

Comment: Or `sample()` for a random sample of a vector

Comment: Thank you for the lightening fast response! Since the data is private, I do not want to draw a sample from it. As for `rnorm()` and `runif()`, my columns are not normally distributed. Is is possible to simulate data given a specific min, max, mean, and skew?

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what you're trying to accomplish with this generated data? There's a lot of ways to manipulate randomly generated numbers in R, but depending on your use case you may or may not need to replicate every element of your dataset. A simple example is you could generate ages as `age <- sample(1:99, 1000, replace = TRUE)` to generate 1000 data points. If you wanted to match the probability of your dataset, you could calculate the probabilities of age from `1:99` in your dataset, and use `age <- sample(1:99,1000, prob = prob_vector, replace = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses and your answer. I'm going to edit the question in an attempt to improve the quality of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small example with `mtcars`:

Let's say we want to generate a random sample of `cyl`, which has the values `4`, `6`, or `8`, but we want to match the distribution in `mtcars`

First, we need to calculate the probability for each value in the data:

```
set.seed(2)
library(tidyverse)

cyl_pct <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(pct = count/sum(count)) %>% 
  select(pct) %>%
  unlist()
```

Then we take a sample, using the probabilities from our actual data:

`mtcars2 <- data.frame(cyl = sample(c(4,6,8), 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = cyl_pct))`

Now let's check it:

```
mtcars2 %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
      summarize(count = n()) %>% 
      mutate(pct = count/sum(count)) %>% 
      select(pct) %>%
      unlist()

  pct1   pct2   pct3 
0.3495 0.2193 0.4312
```

Compared to the probabilities in `mtcars`

```
   pct1    pct2    pct3 
0.34375 0.21875 0.43750
```

For a larger `n` in `sample`, those percentages will converge to the provided values.

Comment: Your answer worked like a charm once I realized I needed to sort the vector I was passing to my new dataframe:

`df_2$var <- data.frame(var = sample(sort(unique(orignial_var)), 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = var_pct))`

Once again, I can't thank you enough because now I can create my simulated dataset and start my blog :) Cheers!